# Preserve formatting while fetching GitHub file contents

Tags: javascript, github, formatting, fetch-api

One can fetch the contents of [a file in a GitHub repository](https://github.com/Ayanmullick/test/blob/master/AutomationAcc/test1.ps1) using the code below.

```js
fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ayanmullick/test/master/AutomationAcc/test1.ps1")
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => document.write(data))
```

However, the formatting gets lost. I faced the same problem [with the api](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/scripting-with-the-rest-api-and-javascript?apiVersion=2022-11-28) too.

```js
fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/Ayanmullick/test/git/blobs/97e69f38b60f360dc8a22e07c6c395feb0e004a8")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => atob(data.content))
        .then(decoded =>document.write(decoded))
```

Is there a way to preserve the formatting while fetching the file contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't that `fetch()` is loosing your formatting, it is that `document.write()` won't write whitespace. You can see this by `console.log()`ing instead:

```js
fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ayanmullick/test/master/AutomationAcc/test1.ps1")
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => console.log(data))
```

If you need to write it to the DOM, try using a [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag that preserves whitespace exactly:

```js
fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ayanmullick/test/master/AutomationAcc/test1.ps1")
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => document.getElementById('code').textContent = data)
```

```html
<pre id="code"></pre>
```